# automation to shrink page margins in pdf

Tags: pdf, mupdf, qpdf

I happen to have dozens of pdfs with over 500 pages in each.  They written content in all these pdf occupy a small portion in the center of the page leaving a lot of margin outside of the page.  This shrinks the character size.  I am trying to see if there is a way to stretch the written content to occupy more page (zoom in with constant page size).  Is there any pdf tool that can help me trim the top/bottom/right/left margin in bulk?  Something that takes pdf as input and page ranges to modify this way?

See the image to understand my scenario.

Thanks

[a page from the pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubzs4.png)

Comment: Not looking for printing, i want to display on digital devices. The text content in center should occupy more canvas/media.

Comment: Thank you so much for this hack.  My pdf happens to be textual one that i use pdfjs to display with online.  Rather than hacking into binary of pdf is there a way to make pdfjs display it properly?  Here is the pdf

https://assets.studyring.org/assets/books/baws/KN/Volume_22.pdf

Go to a page number like 50 (i use PageFit)
https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html?file=https://assets.studyring.org/assets/books/baws/KN/Volume_22.pdf

Comment: `cpdf in.pdf 5-12 -crop "100 100 500 400" -o out.pdf`, for example, will crop pages 5 to 12 to the given dimensions. PDF viewers will then use the crop box in preference to the media box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "typical" example you supply is not uncommon for this problem task. Often the cover is greater area than subsequent content pages. In addition books often have significantly variable amounts of void space around the body.

You could try to use a viewer in fit content mode but the experience would be highly variable leading to view-sickness (my term for nearest to see-sickness)

[image]

My suggestion is use the venerable "Briss" [(v0.9)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/briss/) or [2.0](https://github.com/mbaeuerle/Briss-2.0) where you can quickly tune manually a good compromise across rafts of erratically variable pages. It took only seconds to download install and set the ideal **manual tweaked** output for the 580 pages using 0.9 to skip page 1. using an auto crop tool usually results in tweaking the outputs in many cases like this one.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.  This seems to be the best way forward for us.  Will give it an attempt.  In the meantime if you can share the pdf you generated from this tool we can check if it meets all our needs.